# how to write multiple JSON files into one csv?

Tags: python, json, csv

I can't find any answers(

i have parsed json from web, this syntax {"a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 3} and transform it to dictonary.

```
url = 'some.url/1'
data = requests.get(url=url)

binary = data.content

output = json.loads(binary)
```

There i have regular dictonary.
And now i need to write "a" and "c" into csv file, but the most difficult problem is that I must have many iterations of this function, ie from some.url/1 to some.url/100, and all output data must be in one file, how do I do this?

Thank you so much

Comment: Use a loop that reads the JSON from each file, then writes a line to the CSV file from that JSON.

Comment: will `data` contain the same static structure `{"a" : ..., "b" : ..., "c" : ...} ` for each url?

Comment: May I ask why you don't keep it in JSON? (curious)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to post an example where you keep json:

```
import random
import json

output = {}

for url in ["url1","url2"]:
    r = {"a" : random.randint(1,10), "b" : random.randint(1,10), "c" : random.randint(1,10)}
    del r["c"]
    output[url] = r

json.dumps(output)


#with open("output.json","w") as f:
#    f.write(json.dumps(output))
```

Returns

```
'{"url1": {"a": 10, "b": 4}, "url2": {"a": 6, "b": 7}}'
```

---

This can be loaded into a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json("output.json").T
print(df)

        a   b
url1    10  6
url2    10  5
```

From here you can do all kind of operations...

Answer (score 2):

Using [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter), assuming that all the document have a consistent structure:

```
import csv
import requests

with open('outfile.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    fieldnames = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    # write the headers, optionally
    writer.writeheader()

    for i in range(1, 101):
        # do you stuff to fetch data
        url = 'some.url/%i' % i
        data = requests.get(url=url)
        binary = data.content
        output = json.loads(binary)

        # now write
        writer.writerow(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop that runs from 1 to 100. Append the loop variable to the URL, get the JSON, parse it, and write what you want to the CSV.

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    csvfile = csv.writer(f)
    for i in range(1, 101):
        url = 'some.url/' + str(i)
        data = requests.get(url=url)
        output = json.loads(data.content)
        csvfile.writerow([output['a'], output['c']])
```

Comment: i have error dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 1, 2, but when i start code from 1st answer whith full wirte it's all right, what is wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting that error. My answer uses a `Writer`, not `DictWriter`, so it expects the row to be a list.